# How do I get grep to exclude specific paths?

Tags: grep

Note: This is NOT a duplicate. I am dealing with a certain instance where grep's options for excluding paths/directories do not behave in an expected way.

I am trying to use grep to recursively search my root filesystem. I am trying to exclude certain directories like `/proc`, `/sys`, and `/usr/local`. If I use `--exclude-dir=${DIR_NAME}`, then it will not search in paths below `${DIR_NAME}`, but this will *also* mean that it will refuse to search paths below `${DIR_NAME}` if `${DIR_NAME}` is at a level below the current working directory. As an example, consider this filesystem tree:

```
${PWD}/
  data/
    settings/
      sys/
    users/
      developer/
        projects/
          my_os/
            build/
            src/
              apps/
              sys/
            Makefile
  extras/
  sys/
    apps/
    os/
```

If I want my search to exclude `${PWD}/sys` and everything under it, `grep -rl --exclude-dir=sys` will exclude it, but it will also exclude `${PWD}/data/settings/sys` and `${PWD}/users/developer/projects/my_os/src/sys`, two directories I want included in my search.

I was originally hoping that `--exclude-dir`/`--exclude` would be allow for regular expressions and I've found [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6565471/how-can-i-exclude-directories-from-grep-r#comment32719649_8692318) indicating that they do, but it seems that regular expression syntax doesn't affect the utility's behavior (e.g, `"^/(dev|proc)"`). I'm fine if those two options don't use regular expressions, but I do not want the exclusion pattern to be applied to singular path components. Is there anyway to get it to work like that?

Comment: [The man page description for that option is sort of misleading... It's pattern as in globs not pattern as in regex.](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/282651/74329)

Answer (score 1):

Simply use this:

```
grep -r "text" | grep -i -v ^sys/
```

You can add so much "| grep -i -v ^dir/" as you need.

Comment: The first grep will still search those directories. So when you get to infinite 'files' like `/dev/random` and `/dev/zero`, it will hang forever. (And also print out a stream of error messages.)